# Pass result of a function from React Js to Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I want to use a text to speech library in React , the library is implemented with pure Javascript and I want to pass a React result which is a text (string) to the functions of this library .

The function with JS :https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-violet-t494o?file=/src/script.js

Comment: you can just refer to the library in your react code

Comment: open the chosen library's documentation, you'll find everything you need there

Comment: Thank you , there is no documentation .

Comment: so this is not a library then, this is some native code using Web Speech API. 
I suggest you include all of your code in a function (delete the text declaration and pass text as a function param). export the function and import it wherever you need to use it, and execute it with the text you want

Answer (score -1):

```
//inside script.js
const TextToSpeech = (text) => {
  const textEl = document.getElementById("text");
  ...
};
export default TextToSpeech;


//inside you react component
import TextToSpeech from 'script.js';
//execute the function with your text
const text="whatever text";
TextToSpeech(text)
```